# Angular2 + express should be run on 2 different server

Tags: express, angular, mean-stack

I am going to create a Application in MEAN 2.0 , is this good idea to create 2 different server one for Angular2 only and other for Express Js (for API only ) .

Or should i use any other pattern ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, why not. So you have the chance to split them to different (physical) servers..

That Express-server could serve your Angular2 app too, but I would split them too.